# Finding the right dimensions of a physics-motivated equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, tensors

I have been trying to find the right dimensions of some functions in the equation

$$\begin{cases}-\rho U\cdot \nabla u = -\nabla p + \nabla^2u \\
\nabla \cdot u = 0 \end{cases}$$

as seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oseen_equations#Equations), in this Wikipedia article about the Oseen equations.

$u$ and $U$ are two velocities, which makes me think they are both vectors of the same dimension $d$ (the dimension we are working on) and they depend on the spatial coordinates (and maybe on time as well). So I think $u, U: \mathbb{R}^d\to \Bbb{R}^d$ or $u,U:\Bbb{R}^{d+1}\to\Bbb{R}^d$. $p$ is the pressure, so I would say it is a scalar function that depends on the spatial coordinates as well, but not on time, so $p: \Bbb{R}^d \to \Bbb{R}$.

I believe my struggle has to do with the fact that I don't know what are the meanings of the operators in the context they are being used.

If $u,U$ and $p$ have the dimensions I think they have, then  $\nabla \cdot u$ is the only thing that I understand. What does the gradient, $\nabla u$, mean? When $u$ is scalar, $\nabla u$ is a vector. What if $u$ is a vector already? Is $\nabla u$ a matrix?

While trying to understand what is going on I read about dyadics in Wikipedia. It felt like it could make sense here, but then what is the meaning of $U\cdot \nabla u$, if $U$ is a vector and $\nabla u$ is a matrix?

And of course, $\nabla^2$ which I know is the Laplace operator, with which I am also familiar when applied to a scalar function. If $u$ is a vector, then what is $\nabla^2 u$? Is it a vector as well? I think it should be, in order to be summable with $-\nabla p$...

If anyone could point me to something to read/learn in order to be able to understand this, I would be glad. The problem is, I don't even know where to go looking for answers.

Comment: My interpretation based on my experience with physics, is that $\nabla u$ should be thought of as a "vector of vectors," with the $i$th component being the $i$th partial of $u$. Then $U$ is a vector of scalars, so you can take the dot product $U\cdot \nabla u$ to get a vector. However, I'm not *entirely* sure that this is what was intended, but that certainly makes all the dimensions work. (Probably you need to restrict to position partials if this depends on time?)

Comment: @jgon restricting the $\nabla$ to just the spatial coordinates is common practice, I read about it on my quest to understand this... Thinking of $\nabla u$ as a vector of vectors then the $i$th vector of $\nabla u$ would be the divergence of the $i$th component of $u$?

Comment: No, the $i$th vector of $\nabla u$ would be the $i$th partial of $u$, i.e. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} u$.

Comment: Also divergence can't be taken of scalars, and divergence is a scalar not a vector.

Comment: @jgon I meant gradient, not divergence; sorry. Then you say that $U \cdot \nabla u$ would have, as $i$th component, $U \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}u$?

Comment: Ah no, I'm pretty sure that $U\cdot \nabla u$ should be $\sum_i U_i(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} u)$, where $U_i$ is the $i$th component of $U$.

Comment: Look I could be completely wrong, I've never seen a proper definition of gradient of vectors, but based on my experience with similar confusing notation in my physics classes, this is my interpretation of what they are likely to have meant.

Comment: $\nabla \bf{u}$ is a tensor quantity, represented by an $n \times n$ array where $n$ is the length of the vector $\bf{u}$, the velocity vectors are your usual vectors whose components are the derivatives of spatial components wrt time, that is $u_i = \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial t}$ (the same is true for $\bf{U}$, though its the flow of the surrounding fluid far from the object). The quantity $-\nabla p$ is a vector as you suspect since $p$ is a scalar function of the spatial variables.

Comment: A neat thing about the quantity $\nabla \bf{u}$ is that it has a lot of information about $\bf{u}$ rolled up into it, if you take the trace of this matrix it yields the divergence of $\bf{u}$, if you anti-symmetrize it you will obtain a matrix of curl components. The term $\bf{U} \cdot \nabla \bf{u}$, is known as a convective term, the external flowing field $\bf{U}$ carries the "object" $\nabla \bf{u}$ along with it in the fluid.

Comment: @Triatticus very well, that does make some sense. What would then be the different components of the tensor $\nabla u $? I alright got what the diagonal components are. Also, I didn't quite get what you mean by "the external field $U $ carries the 'object' $\nabla u $ along with it in the fluid"... can you refer me to some reading material? I guess a couple of wikipedia articles could suffice (just enough for me to better understand what all this is). Thanks

Comment: A lot of this stuff comes up in continuum mechanics/fluid dynamics where the primary equations of motion are the Navier-Stokes equations. They would have a familiar looking form to the ones you posted. The tensor object will be made up of all combinations of derivatives of components of $u$, in the form $\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}$, it's very similar in structure to a Jacobian matrix.

Comment: As for the convective term, imagine it this way,say you drop some dye in clear shallow water, naturally the dye will spread out due to Brownian motion and density gradients. If the surrounding water is calm the dye will only diffuse (there is a diffusion term in the N-S equations not present in the ones you posted.). Now if the water has a flow to it, the spreading dye will be carried along as it spreads, this is the convective part, if you took successive snap shots the dye will have spread and moved along with the flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nabla notation is rather abstract: its purpose is to act as shorthand in long expressions with partial derivatives. Think of $\nabla$ as a vector operator, which has components
$$ \vec\nabla = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial_x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial_y}, \frac{\partial}{\partial_z}\right) $$

It does not matter to what kind of function you apply it, the effect is always
$$ (\nabla f)_i = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} $$

The question is, what mathematical meaning can be given to the RHS for each particular $f$. If $f$ is a scalar, then each component of $\nabla f$ is a single real function, and together they make a vector (it would be inaccurate to say that each component is a scalar, because they don't transform as scalars under coordinate transformations) - this is called the gradient of $f$. If $\bf f$ is a vector, the partial derivatives act on each of its components independently (this is as if we multiply the vector $\bf f$ with the "scalar" $\partial/\partial x_i$), so each "component" of $\nabla \bf f$ is a triple of real numbers, and so long as you don't make any coordinate transformations, their combined structure can be adequately represented by a matrix - but be careful not to mix up row vectors with column vectors; you should think of the first one ($\nabla$) as column and the second one ($\bf f$) as row to get a matrix.

This way of multiplying vectors is referred to as an [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) to contrast it with the inner (a.k.a. dot) product, which involves summation over indices; in the latter, when the del operator is involved, as in $\nabla \cdot \bf f$, each $\partial/\partial x_i$ acts only on the corresponding $f_i$, and the end result is the sum of all those, a scalar called the divergence of $\bf f$ (in the matrix notation, this time the first is the row and the second is the column, to produce a $1\times 1$ matrix which can represent a scalar).

If you combine more than two vectors, some of which can be $\nabla$'s, it is very important also to keep track of what is multiplied with what, and in what way. Just as with ordinary vectors, $\bf (a\cdot b)c$ is very different from $\bf a(b \cdot c)$; the reason they are different is not that these multiplications aren't associative (they are); the reason is that the dot product is not the same kind of product as the product of scalar with vector (in fact, the latter is actually more like an outer product), so we can't just switch them around. With two nablas, for example, we can have
$$
(\nabla \cdot \nabla) {\bf f} = \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial_x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial_y^2}+ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial_z^2}\right) {\bf f} = \nabla^2 \bf f$$

This is an example of Laplace's operator, which is a scalar operator, acting on a vector - it just acts on each component separately, just as $a{\bf u} = (au_x, au_y, au_z)$ for any scalar $a$. But it is not the same thing as $\nabla (\nabla \cdot \bf f)$, the gradient of the divergence of $\bf f$.

In the case of $\bf U\cdot \nabla \bf u$, the order in which multiplications are carried out is irrelevant, so long as the correct type of multiplications is performed for each. But, as anyone who has done large matrix computations will tell you, it is more efficient to work with lower rank objects. It is also easier to visualize the intermediate objects that way. So I would argue that the better way to imagine it is
$$
({\bf U} \cdot \nabla) {\bf u} = \left(U_x\frac{\partial}{\partial_x} + U_y\frac{\partial}{\partial_y}+ U_z\frac{\partial}{\partial_z}\right) \bf u $$

The object in the parenthesis doesn't have components; it is the scalar (operator) $\bf U \cdot \nabla$; when multiplied with the vector $\bf u$ it produces a vector, and the multiplication proceeds according to the principles of multiplication of vector with scalar - each component of $\bf u$ gets acted on by that operator independently of the others.

In the matrix notation, this would be written with $\bf U$ as a row vector, $\nabla$ as column, and $\bf u$ as row. The result will be a row vector with the same structure as the row vector $\bf u$.

Comment: One first skim through your answer makes me feel yours is the answer I have been looking for. Either way, why is $U\cdot \nabla u $ computed as $(U\cdot \nabla)u$ and not $U\cdot(\nabla u) $?

Comment: you can compute it either way, the result will be the same (and the matrix way of representing these multiplications makes it obvious that the result will be the same, because matrix multiplication is associative). That's why the parenthesis is often dropped, since it is unnecessary. What is important is that the $\bf U \cdot \nabla$ is an inner product (which involves summation over indices), while the $\nabla \bf u$ is what is called outer (or tensor) product; if you are not used to that, it is easier to do $\bf U \cdot \nabla$ first, then you are left with just scalar times vector.

Comment: @RGS, I edited the answer to reflect some of the points I made in the comment above, and included a reference to wikipedia page for outer product, it may be helpful if you want to get a better idea of how this fits into the framework of linear algebra.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts. I think I got it now. Either way, I will be exposed to these things a lot from now on. Would you say it is helpful if I read a bit about tensor calculus? In particular, do you think [this](http://www.ita.uni-heidelberg.de/~dullemond/lectures/tensor/tensor.pdf) pdf could be of help?

Comment: Certainly it would be helpful to read some course on tensor calculus. There is not single answer to which and how much of it, that is very subjective. These days there are so many readily available, that all you have to do is pick one, and if you don't like it, try another. Start with an introductory one, then take it from there. If you find that it is insufficient, follow the references in it to find a more in-depth, or more rigorous, or more extensive one, whichever is needed. @RGS