# Finding the right way to compute tensors and their products

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tensor-products

As a follow-up from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2589503/finding-the-right-dimensions-of-a-physics-motivated-equation) question of mine, I was reading about the vector Laplacian on wikipedia and in the end of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Laplacian#Generalization) section, it looks to me as if there is a contradiction of some kind.

Let $u = (u_x, u_y, u_z)$ and $U = (U_x, U_y, U_z)$ be functions of $x, y, z$.

At first, it is written that for $u$, $\nabla u$ would be

$$\begin{bmatrix}u_{xx} & u_{xy} & u_{xz} \\
u_{yx} & u_{yy} & u_{yz} \\
u_{zx} & u_{zy} & u_{zz}
\end{bmatrix}$$

with

$$u_{ab} = \frac{\partial u_a}{\partial b}$$

and then it is written that $U \cdot \nabla u$ would be

$$U \cdot \nabla u = \begin{bmatrix}U_x & U_y & U_z\end{bmatrix}\nabla u = \begin{bmatrix}U\cdot \nabla u_x & U\cdot \nabla u_y & U\cdot \nabla u_z \end{bmatrix} \tag{1}$$

but if I write that out, it won't match with the matrix multiplication that arises from

$$\begin{bmatrix}U_x & U_y & U_z\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u_{xx} & u_{xy} & u_{xz} \\
u_{yx} & u_{yy} & u_{yz} \\
u_{zx} & u_{zy} & u_{zz}
\end{bmatrix} \tag{2}$$

For example, the first component in $(1)$ is

$$U_xu_{xx} + U_yu_{xy} + U_zu_{xz}$$

whereas in $(2)$ the first component is

$$U_xu_{xx} + U_yu_{yx} + U_zu_{zx}$$

Am I getting this right? If so, then which of the two ways is the correct one? If not, where did my reasoning go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but I believe the confusion is arising from the fact that the order in which you take the partial derivatives does not matter, so that in this case: $$u_{yx} = u_{xy}$$ and likewise for the other terms. In other words, the matrix is symmetric.

Comment: Why would the matrix be symmetric out of the box? If $\nabla \times u = 0$ then it is true that the matrix is symmetric. But you don't need to have $\nabla \times u = 0$... I think.

Comment: I am referring to this theorem on the equality of mixed partials:

Comment: derivatives:https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_theorem_on_equality_of_mixed_partials